# Do you think data structure of tasklet_head is wired?

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

I am reading source code of tasklet and try to understand it.

I think data structure of tasklet_head is wired, do you think so.
Why data type of the second element is struct tasklet_struct ** ,it just make source code more complex and confuse people ,writh?
I mean ,why not the author use struct tasklet_struct *tail?
Perhaps the author is so smart ,that I can not understand this kind of simplicity.
If it is true, if you understand it, could you please some hint.

```
398 /*
399  * Tasklets
400  */
401 struct tasklet_head
402 {
403         struct tasklet_struct *head;
404         struct tasklet_struct **tail;
405 };
```

Full source code can be found [here.](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/kernel/softirq.c?a=arm)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the programming question at hand.

Of course *tail and **tail are entirely different things, and that is why it is **tail and not *tail.

You'll hold some kind of tail ref to avoid iterating over the entire linked list to add something on to the end (for O(1) appends rather than O(n)). Tail could have been set to a particular instance, but there will be a reason for this particular implementation strategy. Point to the next field instead, and it's as simple as:

```
new_item->next = NULL;
*tail = new_item;
tail = &(new_item->next);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: iterating over the entire linked list to add something on to the end (for O(1) appends rather than O(n)).  ==>I am sorry, I do not understand why we need to iterate the entire linked list when we add a node to the end. I think the complexity is O(1) . If the author use struct tasklet_struct *tail; the insert operation can be like this: 'if(!tasklet_head->tail) { //insert this node } else {//The linked list is empty, insert and modify tasklet_head->head}'

Comment: @user1296994 Sorry it was poorly worded in my answer - I was just clarifying the reason for holding a tail reference in the interest of thoroughness. From my answer: 'Tail could have been set to a particular instance, but there will be a reason for this particular implementation strategy.' - i.e. the exact reason is down to the choices of the implementor.